# Feedback form each time overwrites one text file with new incoming data

Tags: java, html, forms, file, jsp

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSP Form</title>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="TestFileHandling.jsp" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>User Information</legend>
        <label for="question">Question</label>
        <input type="text" name="question"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above is a simple form that lets the user enter a question before sending it.

```html
<%@page import="myPackage.FileReaderWriter" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Vector" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    Vector<String[]> v = new Vector<String[]>();
    String[] str1 = {request.getParameter("question")};
    v.addElement(str1);
    FileReaderWriter.saveVectorToFile(v, "MyTestFile.txt");
%>
<%
    Vector<String[]> vec = FileReaderWriter.readFileToVector("MyTestFile.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        out.print("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < vec.elementAt(i).length; j++) {
            out.print(vec.elementAt(i)[j] + "|");
        }
%>
<br>
<%
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

This part takes the question entered and saves it to a text file and then opens the file to display whatever is inside.

All this is done through the following java code:

```java
package myPackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;

public class FileReaderWriter {
    public static void saveVectorToFile(Vector<String[]> v, String sFileName) {
        try {
            // Create a new file writer
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);

            // Loop through all the elements of the vector
            for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
                // Capture the index of the last item of each array
                int lastIndex = v.elementAt(i).length - 1;
                // Loop through all the items of the array, except
                // the last one.
                for (int j = 0; j < lastIndex; j++) {
                    // Append the item to the file.
                    writer.append(v.elementAt(i)[j]);
                    // Append a comma after each item.
                    writer.append(',');
                }
                // Append the last item.
                writer.append(v.elementAt(i)[lastIndex]);
                // Append a new line character to the end of the line
                // (i.e. Start new line)
                writer.append('\n');
            }
            // Save and close the file
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        // Catch the exception if an Input/Output error occurs
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Vector<String[]> readFileToVector(String sFileName) {
        // Initialise the BufferedReader
        BufferedReader br = null;

        // Create a new Vector. The elements of this Vector are String arrays.
        Vector<String[]> v = new Vector<String[]>();
        try {
            // Try to read the file into the buffer
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sFileName));
            // Initialise a String to save the read line.
            String line = null;

            // Loop to read all the lines
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // Convert the each line into an array of Strings using
                // comma as a separator
                String[] values = line.split(",");

                // Add the String array into the Vector
                v.addElement(values);
            }
        }
        // Catch the exception if the file does not exist
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Catch the exception if an Input/Output error occurs
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Close the buffer handler
        finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // return the Vector
        return v;
    }
}
```

My problem is that although everything seems to be working, everytime I enter a new question the old one in the text file gets overwritten. Is there a way I can fix this so that every time I enter a new question in the form, it will get added to the textfile along with all the others instead of constantly overwritting it? Thanks for any information or help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a constructor with an `append` option enabled:

```java
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName, true);
```

Comment: I hate it when the answers so simple.. lol, thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 3):

[FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) has a constructor that lets you specify if you want to append to the file, e.g.

```
// Create a new file writer
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the file in append mode:

```java
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName, true);
```

Here is Java documentation on the [FileWriter API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Answer (score 2):

It should be enough to open the file for appending – the default is to rewrite files:

```java
public static void saveVectorToFile(Vector<String[]> v, String sFileName) {
    // Create a new file writer
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName, true);
    // the rest of your code
}
```